# "MDX Format Expression" in Exact Target Report

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am in ExactTarget report section and trying to create a Up/Down Arrow on one of report column which will show if click rate is higher than x amount then Arrow up and if less than x amount then arrow down.

I found MDX Format expression and I using the following expression on Click rate column.

```
case
When [Measures].CurrentMember >= 1.4
Then '|##0.#0%|arrow=up'
When [Measures].CurrentMember <= 1.4
Then '|##0.#0%|arrow=down'
End
```

It shows arrows, but either everyone is down or if change values to 0 then everyone is up :)

Is there anyway I can accomplish this task, by showing if Click rate is higher than x amount then show Arrow up otherwise Show Arrow down for all values?

Answer (score 0):

Solved....

I have to convert values from % to numbers. Like 1.4% is equal to 0.014

```
case
When [Measures].CurrentMember >= 0.014
Then '|##0.#0%|arrow=up'
When [Measures].CurrentMember <= 0.014
Then '|##0.#0%|arrow=down'
End
```